# nginx location block include ampersand

Tags: nginx, erb

I'm trying to extend the location block below to include 'video/?&itemid'

```
location ~ ^/(about-us|home|contact|social)
```

I've updated to:

```
location ~ ^/(about-us|home|contact|social|video\/?)
```

which catches 'video/?'...If I try to include the ampersand or try escaping the ampersand, it doesn't work. Any ideas? The file is nginx.conf.erb.

Comment: anyone??????????????

Comment: If the ampersand is part of the query string, then it is not part of the normalised URI used by the `location` and `rewrite` directives. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#simple_php_site_configuration) for details.